# Get only directories and subdirectories from a given path

Tags: python, list, directory, tuples

I have folders and subfolders as follow. I would like to get in 2 lists the name of each folder (list 1) and the name of each subfolders (list 2) without the hidden folder. The list 2 is a list in list object.
[image]

- Result expected :

  list1 =['Folder 1', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 3', 'Folder 4']
  list2 =[['Sub-folder 1', 'Sub-folder 2'], ['Sub-folder 3', 'Sub-folder 4', 'Sub-folder 5'], ['Sub-folder 6', 'Sub-folder 7'], [] ]

Thx

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where are the `tuples`? Have you considered using a dictionary? What part of the problem has you stumped?

Comment: Suggestion: research `os.walk`.  Then if a question remains after you create some code, revise the question to include runnable code up to the point where there is a remaining issue.

Comment: I do that for the first list 

import os
path = 'projet'
folder = os.listdir(path)
for name in folder:
    if name[0] == ".":
        folder.remove(name)

It seems to works, but for the second I don't succeed to store a list in a list